# IOS clear swift navigation stack for more than one view controller

Tags: swift, navigation, stack, segue

I am new to swift language

I have 4 view controllers in the storyboard

A,B,C and D

A to B push segue
B to C push Segue
C to D Model segue

When D finishes some work i want to remove
View controller D and C from the navigation stack and 
go back to B as though it is pushed from A to B

I am not sure how to achieve this.
Now i do dismissViewcontrolleranimated in D and it goes
back to C. Then i use back navigation from C to go to B.
But i want to close D and C and directly go to B

Please let me know how we can do this in swift

My app uses IOS8+

Answer (score 1):

If you know the order of the view controllers A, B, C, D then you know that view controller B will have index 1 on the viewControllers property on the navigation controller. If you add the code below to view controller D you should be able to pop to view controller B.

```
navigationController!.popToViewController(navigationController!.viewControllers[1], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have an action button hooked in ViewController D.
Create a segue going from that button to ViewControllerB

```
  @IBAction func actionButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("goToB", sender: self)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    let thirdVC=ThirdViewController()
    thirdVC.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

}
```